I'm looking for a short story I read 10-15 years ago about a man exploring post-apocalyptic Britain
The story involves a man exploring post-apocalyptic Britain. All the people have gone, and he doesn't know why.  Nature is reclaiming the land. The bit that really stuck with me, although it wasn't a major plot point, is there is this tough, toxic grass that has done well since the apocalypse and grown over all the motorways, but the man can't walk on because it hurts his feet, so there is a hint it is genetically modified or something.
I remember it having a lonely vibe, no major drama, just the protagonist musing on all the decay and emptiness but also new growth.

It's a novel, not a short story, but otherwise this matches the book A Scientific Romance by Ronald Wright.
From Goodreads:

It is 1999, and David Lambert, jilted lover and museum curator, is about to discover the startling news of the return of H. G. Wells's time machine to London. Motivated by a host of unanswered questions and innate curiosity, he propels himself deep into the next millenium. As he sets foot in the luxuriant but menacing new landscape, he soon begins to explore the ruins of his life, a labyrinth of erotic obsession and remorse involving his old friend Bird, and Anita -- the beautiful, eccentric Egyptologist they both loved, mysteriously dead at thirty-two.)

As you remember, he travels Britain along the motorways, which have been colonised by a genetically-modified grass.

If it helps, the genetically modified grass is called Supergrass in the book.
